# How do you remove an InfoPath Form or Restore a Default?

Tags: infopath

How do you remove an InfoPath Form or Restore a Default Form?

Answer (score 0):

If this is normal list or library You need to go to the library settings form settings from here you can switch from IP form to the default form. If this is form library the only option is IP form.